# How to debug crashing Pi?

Tags: raspbian, boot

Running newest firmware on a Piv2 with raspbian wheezy. rsyslogd is installed and running.

Looking for suggestions on other ways to debug. Either getting more logging, looking at different logs, installing another logging service, etc. Anything that will help me figure this out.

I have watchdog running. The Pi is running motion and some python code I wrote to take temperature, light level and humidity readings and write them to a google spreadsheet.  The motion video files are being written to the local filesystem and there is plenty of file space. Motion is using the Pi camera module.

System seems to crash every few hours. I have no idea why. Syslog has a bunch of non-printable characters where there should be info about the reboot. Might be a network issue causing the problem but I can't be sure because I don't see the watchdog error that caused the reboot in the logs. Any pointers on how to get more logging done so I can figure this out would be appreciated.

Motion is absolutely the instigator of the issue. I have another Pi running on the same wifi AP and it runs weeks with no issue. This Pi can also run weeks with no issue on Wifi. But as soon as I put motion into the picture it can't even make it a day. Motion runs fine if I'm using a wired connection. So the combination that causes the issue is motion + wifi.

I think it's a network issue because before I had problems the setup was hardwired to the network and ran for days/weeks with no issues. The only change was the location which now requires the use of wifi. So the change that seemed to trigger issues is the move from ethernet (eth0) to wifi (wlan0).

Logs I'm looking at:
/var/log/syslog (non-printable chars where error happened)
/var/log/dmesg (no relevant msgs that I can find)
/var/log/watchdog/repair-bin.stdout & repair-bin.stderr (non-printable chars where error happened)

I'm also looking at a log of the stderr and stdout from the python program I wrote.

Here's a section of the syslog in question:

```
Jun 24 07:05:38 weatherPi watchdog[2552]: got answer from target 192.168.0.1
Jun 24 07:05:43 weatherPi watchdog[2552]: still alive after 2000 interval(s)
Jun 24 07:09:01 weatherPi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2854]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Jun 24 07:17:01 weatherPi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2912]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Jun 24 07:17:10 weatherPi kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jun 24 07:17:10 weatherPi rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="2049" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jun 24 07:17:10 weatherPi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
...snip...
```

Same thing is happening in the repair logs.

Here is the motion.conf (removed some comments to stay within char limit):

```
weather@weatherpi ~/weather/config $ more motion.conf
# Rename this distribution example file to motion.conf
#
# This config file was generated by motion 3.2.12


############################################################
# Daemon
############################################################

# Start in daemon (background) mode and release terminal (default: off)
daemon on

# File to store the process ID, also called pid file. (default: not defined)
process_id_file /var/run/motion/motion.pid 

############################################################
# Basic Setup Mode
############################################################

# Start in Setup-Mode, daemon disabled. (default: off)
setup_mode off

###########################################################
# Capture device options
############################################################

# Videodevice to be used for capturing  (default /dev/video0)
# for FreeBSD default is /dev/bktr0
videodevice /dev/video0


v4l2_palette 8

# Tuner device to be used for capturing using tuner as source (default /dev/tune
r0)
# This is ONLY used for FreeBSD. Leave it commented out for Linux
; tunerdevice /dev/tuner0

# The video input to be used (default: 8)
# Should normally be set to 0 or 1 for video/TV cards, and 8 for USB cameras
input 8

# The video norm to use (only for video capture and TV tuner cards)
# Values: 0 (PAL), 1 (NTSC), 2 (SECAM), 3 (PAL NC no colour). Default: 0 (PAL)
norm 0

# The frequency to set the tuner to (kHz) (only for TV tuner cards) (default: 0)
frequency 0

# Rotate image this number of degrees. The rotation affects all saved images as
# well as mpeg movies. Valid values: 0 (default = no rotation), 90, 180 and 270.
rotate 0

# Image width (pixels). Valid range: Camera dependent, default: 352
#width 1280
width 2592
#width 640

# Image height (pixels). Valid range: Camera dependent, default: 288
#height 720
height 1936
#height 480

# Maximum number of frames to be captured per second.
# Valid range: 2-100. Default: 100 (almost no limit).
framerate 10

# Minimum time in seconds between capturing picture frames from the camera.
# Default: 0 = disabled - the capture rate is given by the camera framerate.
# This option is used when you want to capture images at a rate lower than 2 per
 second.
minimum_frame_time 0

# URL to use if you are using a network camera, size will be autodetected (incl 
http:// ftp:// or file:///)
# Must be a URL that returns single jpeg pictures or a raw mjpeg stream. Default
: Not defined
; netcam_url value

# Username and password for network camera (only if required). Default: not defi
ned
# Syntax is user:password
; netcam_userpass value

# The setting for keep-alive of network socket, should improve performance on co
mpatible net cameras.
# 1.0:         The historical implementation using HTTP/1.0, closing the socket 
after each http request.
# keep_alive:  Use HTTP/1.0 requests with keep alive header to reuse the same co
nnection.
# 1.1:         Use HTTP/1.1 requests that support keep alive as default.
# Default: 1.0
; netcam_http 1.0

# URL to use for a netcam proxy server, if required, e.g. "http://myproxy".
# If a port number other than 80 is needed, use "http://myproxy:1234".
# Default: not defined
; netcam_proxy value 

# Set less strict jpeg checks for network cameras with a poor/buggy firmware.
# Default: off
netcam_tolerant_check off

# Let motion regulate the brightness of a video device (default: off).
# The auto_brightness feature uses the brightness option as its target value.
# If brightness is zero auto_brightness will adjust to average brightness value 
128.
# Only recommended for cameras without auto brightness
auto_brightness off

# Set the initial brightness of a video device.
# If auto_brightness is enabled, this value defines the average brightness level
# which Motion will try and adjust to.
# Valid range 0-255, default 0 = disabled
brightness 0

# Set the contrast of a video device.
# Valid range 0-255, default 0 = disabled
contrast 0

# Set the saturation of a video device.
# Valid range 0-255, default 0 = disabled
saturation 0

# Set the hue of a video device (NTSC feature).
# Valid range 0-255, default 0 = disabled
hue 0


############################################################
# Round Robin (multiple inputs on same video device name)
############################################################

# Number of frames to capture in each roundrobin step (default: 1)
roundrobin_frames 1

# Number of frames to skip before each roundrobin step (default: 1)
roundrobin_skip 1

# Try to filter out noise generated by roundrobin (default: off)
switchfilter off


############################################################
# Motion Detection Settings:
############################################################

# Threshold for number of changed pixels in an image that
# triggers motion detection (default: 1500)
threshold 900

# Automatically tune the threshold down if possible (default: off)
threshold_tune off

# Noise threshold for the motion detection (default: 32)
noise_level 32

# Automatically tune the noise threshold (default: on)
noise_tune on

# Despeckle motion image using (e)rode or (d)ilate or (l)abel (Default: not defi
ned)
# Recommended value is EedDl. Any combination (and number of) of E, e, d, and D 
is valid.
# (l)abeling must only be used once and the 'l' must be the last letter.
# Comment out to disable
despeckle EedDl

# Detect motion in predefined areas (1 - 9). Areas are numbered like that:  1 2 
3
# A script (on_area_detected) is started immediately when motion is         4 5 
6
# detected in one of the given areas, but only once during an event.        7 8 
9
# One or more areas can be specified with this option. (Default: not defined)
; area_detect value

# PGM file to use as a sensitivity mask.
# Full path name to. (Default: not defined)
; mask_file value
;mask_file value /home/weather/weather/config/garden_filter.pgm

# Dynamically create a mask file during operation (default: 0)
# Adjust speed of mask changes from 0 (off) to 10 (fast)
smart_mask_speed 0

# Ignore sudden massive light intensity changes given as a percentage of the pic
ture
# area that changed intensity. Valid range: 0 - 100 , default: 0 = disabled
lightswitch 0

# Picture frames must contain motion at least the specified number of frames
# in a row before they are detected as true motion. At the default of 1, all
# motion is detected. Valid range: 1 to thousands, recommended 1-5
minimum_motion_frames 1

# Specifies the number of pre-captured (buffered) pictures from before motion
# was detected that will be output at motion detection.
# Recommended range: 0 to 5 (default: 0)
# Do not use large values! Large values will cause Motion to skip video frames a
nd
# cause unsmooth mpegs. To smooth mpegs use larger values of post_capture instea
d.
pre_capture 2

# Number of frames to capture after motion is no longer detected (default: 0)
post_capture 2

# Gap is the seconds of no motion detection that triggers the end of an event
# An event is defined as a series of motion images taken within a short timefram
e.
# Recommended value is 60 seconds (Default). The value 0 is allowed and disables
# events causing all Motion to be written to one single mpeg file and no pre_cap
ture.
gap 60

# Maximum length in seconds of an mpeg movie
# When value is exceeded a new mpeg file is created. (Default: 0 = infinite)
max_mpeg_time 300

# Always save images even if there was no motion (default: off)
output_all off


############################################################
# Image File Output
############################################################



output_motion off

# The quality (in percent) to be used by the jpeg compression (default: 75)
quality 100

# Output ppm images instead of jpeg (default: off)
ppm off


############################################################
# FFMPEG related options
# Film (mpeg) file output, and deinterlacing of the video input
# The options movie_filename and timelapse_filename are also used
# by the ffmpeg feature
############################################################

# Use ffmpeg to encode mpeg movies in realtime (default: off)
ffmpeg_cap_new on

# Use ffmpeg to make movies with only the pixels moving
# object (ghost images) (default: off)
ffmpeg_cap_motion off

# Use ffmpeg to encode a timelapse movie 
# Default value 0 = off - else save frame every Nth second
ffmpeg_timelapse 0

# The file rollover mode of the timelapse video
# Valid values: hourly, daily (default), weekly-sunday, weekly-monday, monthly, 
manual
ffmpeg_timelapse_mode daily

# Bitrate to be used by the ffmpeg encoder (default: 400000)
# This option is ignored if ffmpeg_variable_bitrate is not 0 (disabled)
ffmpeg_bps 500000

# Enables and defines variable bitrate for the ffmpeg encoder.
# ffmpeg_bps is ignored if variable bitrate is enabled.
# Valid values: 0 (default) = fixed bitrate defined by ffmpeg_bps,
# or the range 2 - 31 where 2 means best quality and 31 is worst.
ffmpeg_variable_bitrate 0

# Codec to used by ffmpeg for the video compression.
# Timelapse mpegs are always made in mpeg1 format independent from this option.
# Supported formats are: mpeg1 (ffmpeg-0.4.8 only), mpeg4 (default), and msmpeg4
.
# mpeg1 - gives you files with extension .mpg
# mpeg4 or msmpeg4 - gives you files with extension .avi
# msmpeg4 is recommended for use with Windows Media Player because
# it requires no installation of codec on the Windows client.
# swf - gives you a flash film with extension .swf
# flv - gives you a flash video with extension .flv
# ffv1 - FF video codec 1 for Lossless Encoding ( experimental )
# mov - QuickTime ( testing )
ffmpeg_video_codec msmpeg4

# Use ffmpeg to deinterlace video. Necessary if you use an analog camera
# and see horizontal combing on moving objects in video or pictures.
# (default: off)
ffmpeg_deinterlace off


############################################################
# Snapshots (Traditional Periodic Webcam File Output)
############################################################

# Make automated snapshot every N seconds (default: 0 = disabled)
snapshot_interval 3600



# Locate and draw a box around the moving object.
# Valid values: on, off and preview (default: off)
# Set to 'preview' will only draw a box in preview_shot pictures.
locate on

# Draws the timestamp using same options as C function strftime(3)
# Default: %Y-%m-%d\n%T = date in ISO format and time in 24 hour clock
# Text is placed in lower right corner
text_right %Y-%m-%d\n%T-%q

# Draw a user defined text on the images using same options as C function strfti
me(3)
# Default: Not defined = no text
# Text is placed in lower left corner
; text_left CAMERA %t

# Draw the number of changed pixed on the images (default: off)
# Will normally be set to off except when you setup and adjust the motion settin
gs
# Text is placed in upper right corner
text_changes off

# This option defines the value of the special event conversion specifier %C
# You can use any conversion specifier in this option except %C. Date and time
# values are from the timestamp of the first image in the current event.
# Default: %Y%m%d%H%M%S
# The idea is that %C can be used filenames and text_left/right for creating
# a unique identifier for each event.
text_event %Y%m%d%H%M%S

# Draw characters at twice normal size on images. (default: off)
text_double on



# Target base directory for pictures and films
# Recommended to use absolute path. (Default: current working directory)
#target_dir /tmp/motion
target_dir /home/weather/sec_video

# File path for snapshots (jpeg or ppm) relative to target_dir
# Default: %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S-snapshot
# Default value is equivalent to legacy oldlayout option
# For Motion 3.0 compatible mode choose: %Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S-snapshot
# File extension .jpg or .ppm is automatically added so do not include this.
# Note: A symbolic link called lastsnap.jpg created in the target_dir will alway
s
# point to the latest snapshot, unless snapshot_filename is exactly 'lastsnap'
snapshot_filename %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S-snapshot

# File path for motion triggered images (jpeg or ppm) relative to target_dir
# Default: %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S-%q
# Default value is equivalent to legacy oldlayout option
# For Motion 3.0 compatible mode choose: %Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S-%q
# File extension .jpg or .ppm is automatically added so do not include this
# Set to 'preview' together with best-preview feature enables special naming
# convention for preview shots. See motion guide for details
jpeg_filename %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S-%q

# File path for motion triggered ffmpeg films (mpeg) relative to target_dir
# Default: %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S
# Default value is equivalent to legacy oldlayout option
# For Motion 3.0 compatible mode choose: %Y/%m/%d/%H%M%S
# File extension .mpg or .avi is automatically added so do not include this
# This option was previously called ffmpeg_filename
movie_filename %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S

# File path for timelapse mpegs relative to target_dir
# Default: %Y%m%d-timelapse
# Default value is near equivalent to legacy oldlayout option
# For Motion 3.0 compatible mode choose: %Y/%m/%d-timelapse
# File extension .mpg is automatically added so do not include this
timelapse_filename %Y%m%d-timelapse


############################################################
# Live Webcam Server
############################################################

# The mini-http server listens to this port for requests (default: 0 = disabled)
webcam_port 8081

# Quality of the jpeg (in percent) images produced (default: 50) 
webcam_quality 40

# Output frames at 1 fps when no motion is detected and increase to the
# rate given by webcam_maxrate when motion is detected (default: off)
webcam_motion off

# Maximum framerate for webcam streams (default: 1)
webcam_maxrate 1

# Restrict webcam connections to localhost only (default: on)
webcam_localhost off

# Limits the number of images per connection (default: 0 = unlimited)
# Number can be defined by multiplying actual webcam rate by desired number of s
econds
# Actual webcam rate is the smallest of the numbers framerate and webcam_maxrate
webcam_limit 0


############################################################
# HTTP Based Control
############################################################

# TCP/IP port for the http server to listen on (default: 0 = disabled)
control_port 8080

# Restrict control connections to localhost only (default: on)
control_localhost off

# Output for http server, select off to choose raw text plain (default: on)
control_html_output on

# Authentication for the http based control. Syntax username:password
# Default: not defined (Disabled)
control_authentication ifermon:8hemlock


############################################################
# Tracking (Pan/Tilt)
############################################################

# Type of tracker (0=none (default), 1=stepper, 2=iomojo, 3=pwc, 4=generic, 5=uv
cvideo)
# The generic type enables the definition of motion center and motion size to
# be used with the conversion specifiers for options like on_motion_detected
track_type 0

# Enable auto tracking (default: off)
track_auto off

# Serial port of motor (default: none)
; track_port value

# Motor number for x-axis (default: 0)
track_motorx 0

# Motor number for y-axis (default: 0)
track_motory 0

# Maximum value on x-axis (default: 0)
track_maxx 0

# Maximum value on y-axis (default: 0)
track_maxy 0

# ID of an iomojo camera if used (default: 0)
track_iomojo_id 0

# Angle in degrees the camera moves per step on the X-axis
# with auto-track (default: 10)
# Currently only used with pwc type cameras
track_step_angle_x 10

# Angle in degrees the camera moves per step on the Y-axis
# with auto-track (default: 10)
# Currently only used with pwc type cameras
track_step_angle_y 10

# Delay to wait for after tracking movement as number
# of picture frames (default: 10)
track_move_wait 10

# Speed to set the motor to (stepper motor option) (default: 255)
track_speed 255

# Number of steps to make (stepper motor option) (default: 40)
track_stepsize 40



# Do not sound beeps when detecting motion (default: on)
# Note: Motion never beeps when running in daemon mode.
quiet on

# Command to be executed when an event starts. (default: none)
# An event starts at first motion detected after a period of no motion defined b
y gap 
; on_event_start value

# Command to be executed when an event ends after a period of no motion
# (default: none). The period of no motion is defined by option gap.
; on_event_end value

# Command to be executed when a picture (.ppm|.jpg) is saved (default: none)
# To give the filename as an argument to a command append it with %f
; on_picture_save value

# Command to be executed when a motion frame is detected (default: none)
; on_motion_detected value

# Command to be executed when motion in a predefined area is detected
# Check option 'area_detect'.   (default: none)
; on_area_detected value

# Command to be executed when a movie file (.mpg|.avi) is created. (default: non
e)
# To give the filename as an argument to a command append it with %f
; on_movie_start value

# Command to be executed when a movie file (.mpg|.avi) is closed. (default: none
)
# To give the filename as an argument to a command append it with %f
; on_movie_end value

# Command to be executed when a camera can't be opened or if it is lost
# NOTE: There is situations when motion doesn't detect a lost camera!
# It depends on the driver, some drivers don't detect a lost camera at all
# Some hang the motion thread. Some even hang the PC! (default: none)
; on_camera_lost value

############################################################
# Common Options For MySQL and PostgreSQL database features.
# Options require the MySQL/PostgreSQL options to be active also.
############################################################

# Log to the database when creating motion triggered image file  (default: on)
sql_log_image off

# Log to the database when creating a snapshot image file (default: on)
sql_log_snapshot off

# Log to the database when creating motion triggered mpeg file (default: off)
sql_log_mpeg off

# Log to the database when creating timelapse mpeg file (default: off)
sql_log_timelapse off

# SQL query string that is sent to the database
# Use same conversion specifiers has for text features
# Additional special conversion specifiers are
# %n = the number representing the file_type
# %f = filename with full path
# Default value:
# insert into security(camera, filename, frame, file_type, time_stamp, text_even
t) values('%t', '%f', '%q', '%n', '%Y-%m-%d %T', '%C')
sql_query insert into security(camera, filename, frame, file_type, time_stamp, e
vent_time_stamp) values('%t', '%f', '%q', '%n', '%Y-%m-%d %T', '%C')


############################################################
# Database Options For MySQL
############################################################

# Mysql database to log to (default: not defined)
; mysql_db value

# The host on which the database is located (default: localhost)
; mysql_host value

# User account name for MySQL database (default: not defined)
; mysql_user value

# User password for MySQL database (default: not defined)
; mysql_password value


############################################################
# Database Options For PostgreSQL
############################################################

# PostgreSQL database to log to (default: not defined)
; pgsql_db value

# The host on which the database is located (default: localhost)
; pgsql_host value

# User account name for PostgreSQL database (default: not defined)
; pgsql_user value

# User password for PostgreSQL database (default: not defined)
; pgsql_password value

# Port on which the PostgreSQL database is located (default: 5432)
; pgsql_port 5432


############################################################
# Video Loopback Device (vloopback project)
############################################################

# Output images to a video4linux loopback device
# The value '-' means next available (default: not defined)
; video_pipe value

# Output motion images to a video4linux loopback device
# The value '-' means next available (default: not defined)
; motion_video_pipe value



# Remember: If you have more than one camera you must have one
# thread file for each camera. E.g. 2 cameras requires 3 files:
# This motion.conf file AND thread1.conf and thread2.conf.
# Only put the options that are unique to each camera in the
# thread config files. 
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread1.conf
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread2.conf
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread3.conf
; thread /usr/local/etc/thread4.conf

# Set the authentication method (default: 0)
# # 0 = disabled 
# # 1 = Basic authentication
# # 2 = MD5 digest (the safer authentication)
;stream_auth_method 1

#
# # Authentication for the http based control. Syntax username:password
# # Default: not defined (Disabled)
;stream_authentication username:password
weather@weatherpi ~/weather/config $
```

Comment: So what's `run-parts`?

Comment: It's a utility used by cron to run all the scripts in a directory. In this case it runs all the scripts in /etc/cron.hourly. That runs every hour, so I don't think it's an issue. The only script there is fake-hwclock which updates the clock value.

Comment: Can you provide me with the output of `ls /etc | grep weatherPi` and `locate weatherPi.conf`?

Comment: There are no files with weatherPi in their names in /etc. There is also no file named weatherPi.conf on the system.<br> Not sure what you mean by "locate" - I can't find a command by that name. I did run "find / -name weatherPi.conf 2>/dev/null" and it returned no results.

Comment: I would suspect a kernel panic as it is rebooting automatically and there is not trace of what has happen. I would try to install and configure kdump (if it works on ARM/Raspberry Pi) which is the kernel core dump facility (equivalent of a blue screen of death dumping its memory on Windows). Then it is possible to analyse the core dumped by kdump. Most likely the culprit is the wifi module (driver) you are using if that's the only change you did.

Comment: makedumpfile, required by kdump, doesn't seem to be available (sudo apt-get install kdump-tools, or sudo apt-get install makedumpfile)

Comment: use `dtrace` ...

Comment: Do you have any 'hourly crons'?

Comment: I do have con jobs, but not hourly.

Comment: The ^@ are nulls, your syslog is probably open the time of the crash. See /var/log/dmesg after the reboot for lines like: 
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): orphan cleanup on readonly fs  ; EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): 6 orphan inodes deleted  ; EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): recovery complete  ; EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null);

Answer (score 1):

I have had crash trouble with `motion` on my Rpi2. I couldn't work out exactly what this was, but it did write rubbish into logs too. I am sure it was that, when switched off, the rest of the system ran [and runs] until shutdown. My setup uses the Rpi camera module rather than a webcam.

So I'd suggest, as a systematic debug process, switch off `motion` and [if you can] switch off the other bits one by one, to try and isolate the component that causes the crash.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. Motion is absolutely the component that brings out the issue. My question is what is it about motion that causes the network issue, and why only with wifi?

Comment: No problem. Useful for both of us to somewhat replicate it. I can't do something right away, but I can try and replicate the `eth0 -> wlan0` switch in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a very similar problem in my testing and would suggest running your code with strace option to log it to a file. strace shows you all of the system calls your code is making, which is really useful for debugging.

For example, if your entry point is 'main.py' then you would run

```
strace -o logfile python main.py
```

which would log it to a local file 'logfile'. You can also run it without the '-o' switch if you would like to see the output on stderr.

Sadly, I have not solved my own issues. Have either you or the other gentleman figured out what was causing the issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please separate your answer from that follow-up question and if possible elabarote a little more on how strace helps to solve the issue posted in the question? Thanks.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the tip! I did update my answer, but I'm not sure where I can post my question here since new people are barred from commenting on answers that are not their own.

Comment: I suggest `strace -fvo ...` for further information (-v for unabbreviated output of certain functions, -f for any child processes).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone looking at this in the future, I have a feeling that this is a bug caused by rsyslog itself.

it sounds similar to this:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=122601

do you see any lines like this:?
syslogd-2007 action 17 suspended

basically, by default rsyslogd posts to a Xterminal, that is probably not being listened to, so the messages just pile up and up until it fills up and seems to cause crashes.

that it happens now, is probably because you're just producing more logs.

to stop, go to    /etc and edit rsyslog.conf to comment out the last few lines with a #, (requires sudo/root)

Answer (score 0):

Much time has passed, but this is due to the motion log reaching a critical size. Delete it and restart motion.

Lowering the log-level in /etc/motion/motion.conf will reduce accumulation.